# Setting timers in Unreal Engine C++

Tags: c++, timer, unreal-engine4

I am having trouble creating a timer in Unreal Engine 4. The problem is in GetWorldTimerManager. When I call set timer on this I get an E0070 incomplete  type error. Normally this means that I have failed to include something

```
void ACubeFarmBlock::HandleClicked()
{
    if (!bIsPlanted)
    {
        bIsPlanted = true;

        // Change material
        BlockMesh->SetMaterial(0, OrangeMaterial);

        // Determine when to harvest
        GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(HarvestTimerHandle, &ACubeFarmBlock::Harvest, HarvestTime,false);
    }
}
```

HarvestTimerHandle is defined in the header.
Below is the list of includes. MyActor.h contains a method that defines GetWorldTimerManager so I think I have included everything. It is worth it to note that when I looked the timer function up online I found several sites where this set timer method included a this argument inserted between the HarvestTimerHandle argument and the &ACubeFormBlock::Harvest argument. Including this does not make my error go away.

```
#include "CubeFarmBlock.h"
#include "CubeFarmBlockGrid.h"
#include "UObject/ConstructorHelpers.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
#include "Engine/StaticMesh.h"
#include "Materials/MaterialInstance.h"
#include "MyActor.h"
```

The errors:

> ..\CubeFarmBlock.cpp(76): note: see reference to function template instantiation 
>       'TFunction::TFunction(FunctorType &&)' being compiled 1> 
>       with 1> 
>               [ 1> FunctorType=void (__cdecl ACubeFarmBlock::* )(float) 1> ]
>
> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error (active)
>       E0070   incomplete type is not allowed  CubeFarm    ..\CubeFarmBlock.cpp    78  Severity
>       Code    Description Project File    Line Suppression State Error (active)   E0070
>       incomplete type is not allowed  CubeFarm 
>       ..\CubeFarmBlock.cpp    78

Comment: _When I call set timer on this I get an incomplete bio type error_ Please copy-paste error messages **without** paraphrasing them.

Comment: 1>C:\Users\Teresa\Documents\Unreal Projects\CubeFarm\Source\CubeFarm\CubeFarmBlock.cpp(76): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'TFunction<void (void)>::TFunction<void(__cdecl ACubeFarmBlock::* )(float),void>(FunctorType &&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            FunctorType=void (__cdecl ACubeFarmBlock::* )(float)
1>        ]

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0070 incomplete type is not allowed CubeFarm c:\Users\Teresa\Documents\Unreal Projects\CubeFarm\Source\CubeFarm\CubeFarmBlock.cpp 78 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0070 incomplete type is not allowed CubeFarm c:\Users\Teresa\Documents\Unreal Projects\CubeFarm\Source\CubeFarm\CubeFarmBlock.cpp 78

Comment: Please [edit] Your question, and add all relevant information in the question itself.

Comment: Done! Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 6):

In your header file create a handler `FTimerHandle InputTimeHandle`;

Then in your cpp file

```
GetWorld()->GetTimerManager().SetTimer(InputTimeHandle,this, &AMyPlayerController::GetInputTimer, 1, true,0.5f);
```

You are only missing parameters

Comment: Please mark as answered if your problem is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so for a warning, I've never used UE4, however...

This error says that you are trying to bind a member function to a TFunction:

```
'TFunction::TFunction(FunctorType &&)' being compiled 1> with 1> 
    [ 1> FunctorType=void (__cdecl ACubeFarmBlock::* )(float) 1> ]
```

Member functions need an Object to point to.. I think you are missing the 'this' parameter.  Without looking it up, I think you either need to:

- Bind `this` to the TFunction you are trying to pass the Timer **OR**
- Use another `SetTimer` overload that [lets you pass this as a parameter](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/FTimerManager/SetTimer/6/index.html).

E.g.

```
GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(HarvestTimerHandle, this, &ACubeFarmBlock::Harvest, HarvestTime,false);
```

---

I can't find any simple references online, but if you search for Member Function pointers and perhaps the [hidden this parameter](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/8-8-the-hidden-this-pointer/) you can get an idea as to what is going wrong.

Comment: It looks like I need this. Other people online have used  this in there code successfully. However, it does not make​E0070 go away. Additionally, this introduces a new error: C2664